# Removing drop shadow from windows in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, display-settings

I recently made the switch to Windows 7 and love it. but I was wondering if/how I can turn off the drop shadow on the windows?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to the Control Panel, and click on the System icon.
Under the Advanced tab and Performance section, click on the Settings button.
You'll find there an entry called "Show shadows under windows".:

[image]

Disable it and they're gone.

More information in this thread at [**WindowsSevenForums**](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1908-visual-effects-settings-change.html).

Comment: For the past few days I thought that something was wrong with my monitor, because the left edge of the screen was very dim. Then I realized it was the drop shadow on Visual Studio >.<

Comment: Some applications like Visio 2016 on Windows 7 do not respect this.

Answer (score 3):

None of these worked for me.  What did fix it, however, was unticking "Animate controls and Elements Inside Windows"  under Control Panel, System, Advanced, Performance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click START, right-click Computer and choose **Properties**
2. On the left hand side, click **Advanced System Settings**
3. Click Settings on the **Performance** category
4. From the Visual Effects tab, untick **Show shadows under windows**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ClearType for easier to read on windows 7 ClearType is a software technology developed by microsoft that improves the readability of text on existing LCDs (Liquid Crystal Displays), such as laptop screens, pocket PC screens and flat panel monitors. with ClearType font technology, the words on your computer screen look almost as sharp and clear as those printed on a piece of paper

for enable this option on windows 7 : just go to the fonts center in control panel then you can find " adjust ClearType text" and finaly checkmark turn on Cleartype MBS.

Answer (score 0):

When using a Windows 7 Aero desktop theme, the icon font shadows can be turned off as shown below - system won't let me post images yet so...

1. Open My Computer
2. System Properties
3. Advanced System Settings
4. System Properties
5. Advanced tab
6. Performance Settings
7. UNCHECK first box Animate controls and elements inside windows
8. UNCHECK second last box Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop

If you use a Windows 7 Basic theme, the shadows are turned off automatically but can be turned on
by checking the Use drop shadow box.

Special Notes:
1. Using Windows 7 Basic theme will make it impossible to autohide the play controls
in Windows Media Player.
2. Using Windows 7 Aero desktop themes will allow autohide of Windows Media Player controls only if the last box is checked - Use visual styles on Windows and buttons.