# Is it possible to customise the drop shadow on windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, display-settings

Similar question to [Removing drop shadow from windows in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/113804/removing-drop-shadow-from-windows-in-windows-7), but in this case I want to know whether it's possible to *customise* the drop shadow. I find it too strong, especially on currently focused windows. I'm willing to make changes in registry or use other tools to do so. Specifically, it'd be nice to increase the shadow distance but reduce the strength/opacity.

Comment: Might as well customize the color too.

Answer (score 0):

I is possible, but you need to change windows theme. You can try [Soft7 by ap-graphik](http://ap-graphik.deviantart.com/art/Soft7-2-0-161602097) which is my very favourite. It is almost the same design like original windows 7 theme, but softer and better done. Anyway for your question: right now, there is no way how to do it in registry or in settings.